# HTA Vbscript FileSystemObject and DOM

Tags: dom, vbscript, hta

Below is prototype code, which I am writing for getting content of text files present in a particular folder into div of .hta document.
using document.write I could easily write on document, but I want to write content of text files to specific div.
When I try to run the code, nothing happens.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Notes</title>
<script language="vbscript">
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
FileName = "C:\Documents and Settings\anamdev\Desktop\demo.txt"
Set fileObj = fso.GetFile(FileName)
Set ts = fileObj.OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
Set objDiv = Document.getElementById("content")
objDiv = ts.ReadAll
Do While ts.AtEndOfStream <> True
    TextLine = ts.ReadLine
    Document.getElementById("content").innerHtml TextLine & "<br />"
Loop
ts.Close
</script>
</head>
<body>
<span id="head"></span>
<input type="button" value="Previous" name="pre" />
<input type="button" value="Next" name="nxt" />
<hr>
<div id="content">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you sure that "nothing happens"? Seems like there might at least be a script error message.

Comment: Yes, when I ran above code nothing happened and not even a error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Cheran Shunmugavel [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17247994/1856504) is correct (+1), I'll only append some other issues that I see in the code.

```
Set objDiv = Document.getElementById("content")
objDiv = ts.ReadAll
```

Above not make sense. You set an `Object` to variable `objDiv` and immediately overwrite this variable with `String` on the next line.

Anyway, after `ReadAll` your `TextStream` is already reach EOF, so next loop do nothing:

```
Do While ts.AtEndOfStream <> True
    TextLine = ts.ReadLine
    Document.getElementById("content").innerHtml TextLine & "<br />"
Loop
```

Also the assignment is wrong.

```
Object.Property Value   'incorrect
Object.Property = Value 'correct
```

Briefly, you can go like this:

```
Set objDiv = Document.getElementById("content")
objDiv.innerHtml = ts.ReadAll
ts.Close
```

Comment: 1. Cheran Shunmugavel's advice about script tag position was also equally useful. 2. Oh, that DO. . LOOP was just for showing one of the method I was using to get text file content in HTA document. 3. What I did wrong was using wrong assignment method, as pointed out by Panayot Karabakalov and position of script tag. Script tag should have been after body tag or I should have used, window.onload method. 4. Yeah, now its working.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that the code in your `<script>` is executed as the page is being parsed. This means that at the time the script is run, the "content" element doesn't exist. I would expect that you're actually getting an "Object required" error that isn't being displayed for whatever reason.

There are at least two ways to address this:

1. Move the script block to the end of the document, just before the close `</body>` tag:

   ```
   <html>
   <head>
   <title>Notes</title>
   </head>
   <body>
   <span id="head"></span>
   <input type="button" value="Previous" name="pre" />
   <input type="button" value="Next" name="nxt" />
   <hr>
   <div id="content">
   </div>

   <script language="vbscript">
   Document.getElementById("content").innerHtml = "Hello!"
   </script>
   </body>
   </html>
   ```
2. Wrap the initialization code in a subroutine and call it from the `window` object's `onload` event handler:

   ```
   <html>
   <head>
   <title>Notes</title>
   <script language="vbscript">
   Sub Init
       Document.getElementById("content").innerHtml = "Hello!"
   End Sub

   Set window.onload = GetRef("Init")

   'Alternatively, you could do this to the <body> element:
   '  <body onload="Init()">
   </script>
   </head>
   <body>
   <span id="head"></span>
   <input type="button" value="Previous" name="pre" />
   <input type="button" value="Next" name="nxt" />
   <hr>
   <div id="content">
   </div>
   </body>
   </html>
   ```

Comment: Initialization code should go into a procedure `Sub Window_onLoad`.